# Running Julia .jl file in python

Tags: python, julia

I'm trying to run a Julia `.jl` file in Python, however, after having tried different options none of them is working.

I've tried to use `PyJulia`. Import Julia and define a Julia object. Not achieved.

Has anyone mix Python and Julia technologies and has succeeded? (run Julia from Python)

Comment: What have you tried exactly? What platform are you on? Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you're trying to do with any error messages. As it stands, this question is way too generic.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely right. It was my first post and I'll try to improve progressively. Even if someone has already solve my doubt, thanks you for the help.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

First install `PyCall` package in Julia by running `Pkg.add("PyCall")` in Julia REPL.

Next you need to install `julia` for Python:

```
$ pip install julia
```

should work. Here is the output from my console (you should see something similar):

```
$ pip install julia
Collecting julia
  Downloading julia-0.1.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl (222kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 225kB 1.1MB/s
Installing collected packages: julia
Successfully installed julia-0.1.5
```

Now assume you have the following file `test.jl` in your working directory:

```
for i in 1:10
    println(i)
end
1+2
```

(it should print numbers from 1 to 10, and return value 3 which is the result of sum of 1 and 2).

Now you start Python REPL and use `julia` package as follows to run a custom Julia script:

```
>>> import julia
>>> j = julia.Julia()
>>> x = j.include("test.jl")
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
>>> x
3
```

And as you can see you have the return value of Julia script assigned to variable `x` in Python.

You can find more details here: https://github.com/JuliaPy/pyjulia.

Comment: better do like this:
    'from julia.api import Julia'
    'j = Julia(compiled_modules=False)'

Comment: @Leo Why? What would be the difference?