# How can a Julia module executed using python?

Tags: python, julia

I have created a Julia function with arguments. I have also created python program which intakes some data from the user. How can I import this Julia file into python so that I can call the function as well as pass arguments.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running Julia .jl file in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49750067/running-julia-jl-file-in-python)

Comment: Here is mine tutorial: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64241264/i-have-a-high-performant-function-written-in-julia-how-can-i-use-it-from-python